# AngularJS: Event for loaded template

Tags: angularjs, templates, routes

I write a SPA and use the routing feature.

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/', 
{
    controller: 'SimpleController',
    templateUrl: 'partials/tkm_detailliste.html'
})
```

In the tkm_detailliste.htm I have an div with an id.

```
<div id="myGrid"...
```

Then comes some javascript where I want to instanciate a slik-grid.

```
grid = new Slick.Grid('#myGrid', dataView, columns, options);
```

But at the moment the javascript is executed the div id="myGrid" is not in the DOM so it cant get found.
My workaround is a timeout.

```
setTimeout( function() {
    grid = new Slick.Grid('#myGrid', dataView, columns,options);
, 100);
```

Is there a more elegant intended way to wiring up a loaded template with javascript?

== Update =================

I found a simple solution.

```
SimpleController = function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        grid = new Slick.Grid('#myGrid', dataView, columns, options);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you initialising your slickGrid?

Comment: I did put everything in the tkm_detailliste.html. First the html part and then javascript.

Comment: Your plugin-related javascript should reside inside the directive and definitely not inside the partial.

Answer (score 2):

wire up a directive to that element and then in the link function for it you could emit an event using scope.$emit("ELEMENT READY") to let the rest of the application know that it's good to go.

Comment: Sounds plausible but I am not so far advanced in angularJS to write my own directives.